# Kahler-Einstein Metrics in Physics - Topic Suggestions

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, applications, kahler-manifolds

I am hoping to get some topic suggestions for a presentation I have to give in a couple of weeks. The course the presentation is for is called Kahler-Einstein metrics. I would really like the presentation to be geared towards applying the material we've learned to concepts in physics.

We've learned about Kahler manifolds and their properties, and have spent a bunch of time learning about PDEs. Topics have included Sobolev inequalities, elliptic regularity, Schauder theory and other elliptic PDE stuff. We are also studying the Calabi-Yau theorem.

Any topic suggestions and reference requests are appreciated.

Comment: There are some examples of Kaehler-Einstein metrics appearing in physics given [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/28519?show=28554#a28554). I think those may answer your question.